# When should I use "corpuses" over "corpora"?

Tags: differences, grammatical-number

I've come into a situation where I need to use the plural form of *corpus*, but I'm a bit confused about which plural form to use.

Merriam-Webster [says](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corpus) the only plural form is *corpora*, for all senses of the word. However, Random House/Dictionary.com [says](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/corpus) it's *corpora* for every sense except the linguistic sense:

> *Linguistics* . a body of utterances, as words or sentences, assumed to be representative of and used for lexical, grammatical, or other linguistic analysis.

In this sense, it's *corpuses*.

In my specific situation, I have a collection of data—to be processed—about a class of objects that can be swapped out at will (thus the reference to more than one corpus). To me, this satisfies the first sense of the word ("a large or complete collection of writings")—where the plural is *corpora*—as well as the linguistic sense of the word—where the plural is *corpuses*.

So what's the significant difference between these two senses of the word? When is *corpora* correct, and when is *corpuses* correct?

Comment: It sounds like nobody will ever think you're _wrong_ if you use 'corpora', since according to one source it's always right, and according to the other, it could just as well be right for your use.

Comment: The word as used in linguistics is not at all different from its general meaning: I see no reason, stylistic or otherwise, to differentiate plurals. A collection of sentences etc. is just a specific sub-sense. I and everyone I know just use *corpora* for everything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The OED records *corpora* as the only plural, and that’s all I’ve ever seen in a linguistics context, or in any other for that matter. The entire OED has 71 citations that include *corpora* (admittedly with various meanings) and only one that includes *corpuses*. Corpus data also shows a far higher frequency of *corpora* over *corpuses*. Still, *corpuses* certainly exists, and with no apparent difference in meaning. If you’re conservative, use *corpora*. If you’re feeling adventurous, use *corpuses*.

Comment: So if it shows both *corpora* and *corpuses*, it stands to reason there's a sense in which *corpuses* ought to be used and not *corpora*. That's what my question is about: when to use *corpuses* over *corpora*, not how frequent it appears in the OED.

Comment: @MarkTrapp: When I say ‘corpuses’ appears once in the OED, I mean it appears in only one citation against the 71 in which ‘corpora’ appears. The OED itself records only ‘corpora’ as the plural, although Oxford Dictionaries Online gives both plurals.

Comment: Can you update your answer to explain when I'm supposed to use *corpuses* and when I'm supposed to use *corpora*? That was what I'm interested in, not its frequency of use in a dictionary. I'm assuming now your answer is that *corpuses* is always wrong because it only appears once in the OED: is that a fair assumption? If so, why would it be in the OED at all if it's always wrong?

Comment: @MarkTrapp:Frequency in dictionary citations is relevant, just as frequency in a corpus is relevant. In summary, ‘corpus’ has two plurals, ‘corpora’ and ‘corpuses’ with no difference in meaning, although ‘corpora’ is found more frequently. The choice between the two really makes very little difference, but, at least for the moment, you have the weight of the majority on your side if you use ‘corpora’.

Comment: Can you update your answer to include your conclusion about your findings? Taken as it is now without these comments, I have no idea how I'm supposed to interpret the frequency of the word occurring.

Comment: Done. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

As with many 'correct' Latin terms, the rules for pluralising seem to be changing to adapt to the English language. If your use is formal, then stick with the *corpora*, but if it is a more casual usage, then the (technically incorrect, but accepted in many places) *corpuses* may be used without harm.

(BTW my spell checker complained about *corpuses* but didn't have a problem with *corpora*.)

Comment: Do you have a source for the formal/informal distinction between the two pluralizations?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty clear that a lot more books prefer corpora to corpuses.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=corpuses%2C+corpora&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccorpuses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccorpora%3B%2Cc0